# ubuntu 18.04 mouse,keyboard, power off button stuck

Tags: 18.04, input-devices

After using zoom, my keyboard and touch pad stops working(external mouse still works though), so i went ahead and use the onscreen keyboard to `sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

After rebooting, my external mouse, keyboard and touchpad stopped working. I tried shutting down but it doesn't work too. Am i screwed? What do i do? I am using Dell Inspiron 14 5000

Comment: i unplugged my cmos battery and plugged it back. mouse working now. keyboard not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was such a painful process. I am not even sure if it was due to zoom or what the cause was. To repeat, my keyboard, touch pad AND external devices like mouse and keyboard was not working on ubuntu. I was using a dual boot setup but i could not go into windows as i opted to boot into ubuntu by default and my keyboard was not working.

I opened up my laptop unplugged the laptop battery and cmos battery, plugged them back in and rebooted. At that point my mouse was working but not the keyboard. I went into settings>universal access>onscreen keyboard and entered `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`, rebooted and everything was back to normal. Hopefully it does not happen again...